# offset() of zoomed element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

[jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) for `offset()` states:

> Also, dimensions may be incorrect when the page is zoomed by the user; browsers do not expose an API to detect this condition.

However, is there a way I could calculate the correct offset in browsers in touch environment when using spread to zoom in the contents of a page?

I created a small sample demonstrating the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/dhykgsmp/4/ (open in Chrome). Please scroll down and click zoom in. The offset of the autocomplete input is wrong.

Thank you.

Comment: Define "offset of the autocomplete input is wrong", what do you expect it to be?

Comment: I expect when I set the autocomplete offset values `top` and `left` to another element, the latter to move on top of the autocomplete input. But it doesn't.

Comment: Why do you need dropdown to be absolutely positioned? Can't you make it relative to the input? Then all this positioning magic becomes totally unnecessary. It's just if there is an easier and a more straightforward way, why make it complicated? See here: https://jsfiddle.net/dhykgsmp/5/

Comment: @VictorLevin, I am aware of this approach but I have a more complicated scenario which requires the dropdown to be with `position: absolute`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and found a workaround.
You need a root child element with zero offsets to make this work.

```
$.fn.oldOffset = $.fn.offset;
$.fn.offset = function () {

    var c = $.fn.oldOffset.apply(this, arguments);

    // root child element with zero offset
    var wrc = $('body').children().first().oldOffset();

    var needToFix = wrc.left > 0 || wrc.top > 0;
    if (needToFix) {
        return {
            left: c.left - wrc.left,
            top: c.top - wrc.top
        };
    } else {
        return c;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the intended functionality of this code is, but if you'd like the 'autocomplete input' element to be positioned relative to the 'autocomplete container' I would suggest using the .style.top attribute, or getting the location with Element.getBoundingClientRect() and setting the position accordingly in your positionDropdown() function.